# Selmer: How does one apply filters in a custom tag?

Tags: filter, clojure, tags, selmer

I am playing around with the [Selmer](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer) library (version 1.12.33) and have constructed a simple [custom tag](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer#tags). I want to modify this tag further to allow the use of [filters](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer#filters) in a similar vein how some standard tags, e.g. [`if`](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer#if), [`for`](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer#for), [`script`](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer#script), and [`style`](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer#style) seem to allow it.

Seems the documentation doesn't cover it; **does anyone know how to do this?**

Here is some (very simplified) example code distilling the essence:

## 1. Defining the custom tag:

```clj
(selmer.parser/add-tag! :hello
  (fn [[arg & _] ctx] ; use only first argument
    (let [[name & filters] (clojure.string/split arg #"\|")] ; separate arg1 from appended filter(s)
      (format "Hi, %s!" (or ((keyword name) ctx) name))))) ; look up in context map, else use as-is
```

Obviously, I need to use `filters` here somehow, but I don't know how...

## 2. Rendering the text

```clj
(def myctx {:greet/name "world"})
(selmer.parser/render "{{greet/name|upper|safe}}" myctx)
   ; SUCCESS: expected & actual: WORLD
(selmer.parser/render "{% hello greet/name|upper|safe %}" myctx)
   ; FAIL: Expected: Hi, WORLD!, actual: Hi, world!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the erm, *obvious* way would be to co-opt Selmer to do its stuff on only the input arg, without trying to re-invent Selmer's wheel. The custom tag would then be something like:

```clj
(selmer.parser/add-tag! :hello
  (fn [[arg & _] ctx] ; use only first argument
    (let [name (selmer.parser/render (str "{{" arg "}}") ctx)]
      (format "Hello, %s!" name))))
```

Too obvious? I would be grateful for a better answer or even comments regarding pitfalls with this method, as I am fairly new to Clojure and don't trust my own insight yet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no direct way, but one can build a little util leveraging public selmer functions to do it:

```
(require '[selmer.filter-parser :as htmlp])
(require '[selmer.parser :as html])

(defn resolve-selmer-args
  [args context-map]
  (map #(if (htmlp/literal? %)
          (htmlp/parse-literal %)
          (html/render % context-map)) args))
```